# Windows 10 Build 10512 Set Text Ringtone

Tags: ringtone, insider-preview

Is there any way to change the text message tone in build 10512? I was pretty sure the functionality was there before, but can't find it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the notification settings and tap on messaging link becareful to tap on the messaging no on the icon! There is a setting there for the notification sound.